# How to diplay BoundField Columns values sum in Footer Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, footer

I am binding a gridview, all columns are boundfields :

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="PLAN_SEP" ItemStyle-Width="52px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Plan For The Month" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PLAN_SEP" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ACTUAL_SEP" ItemStyle-Width="52px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Actual For The Month" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ACTUAL_SEP" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="SCORE_FORMONTH" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Score" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SCORE_FORMONTH" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PLAN_LIVE" ItemStyle-Width="52px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Plan Upto Month" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PLAN_LIVE" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ACTUAL_LIVE" ItemStyle-Width="52px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Actual Upto Month" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ACTUAL_LIVE" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="SCORE_UPTOMONTH" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Score" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SCORE_UPTOMONTH" />
```

Now I need to display a footer row which will show sums of respective column values.
Total | total 1 | total 2 | ......

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have to use BoundFields?  Could you use TemplatesFields?  If so, there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: No, as i already have the data saved in database and just need to display it, boundfield is easiest way to use. I cant make this change as i dont have the control. My task is to display total in footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

For bound fields on ly

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
        double total = 0; 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        { 
            string sNum = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;//just changed the index of cells based on your requirements 
            double sum; 
            if(double.TryParse(sNum,out sum)) 
            { 
                total += sum; 
            } 

            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = total.ToString(); 
        } 
 }
```

or

You can make use of databoudnc column and code like this

```
int total = 0;
protected void gvEmp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
       //replace maounty with the name of property 
     total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount"));
  }
  if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.Footer)
  { 
    Label lblamount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
   lblamount.Text = total.ToString();
  }
}
```

Check turotiral : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-display-sum-of-columns-total-in.html

Comment: Can you please also post designer code ? I cant figure out how have you used footer row with boundfields ?

Comment: @HiteshGawhade - hi please check : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-display-sum-of-columns-total-in.html link for all code ..

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done as follows:

In aspx:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
      onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true">
     <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>`

In aspx.cs

```
//Define global variable
int totQty = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        totQty += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Qty"));
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = totQty.ToString();
    }
 }
```

That's it.